# Последовательность в строке

Tags: python

Есть строка. Нужно посчитать самую длинную последовательность определенных символов, например буквы 'а'

Подскажите как справиться

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
s = 'aabbbaaabbbcccaaaaaaadddaa'

count = 0
max_count = 0

for letter in s:
    if letter == 'a':
        count += 1
        max_count = max(count, max_count)
    else:
        count = 0

print(max_count)
```

Answer (score 1):

с использованием регулярных выражений:

```
In [126]: import re

In [127]: s = "aabbbaaabbbcccaaaaaaadddaa"

In [128]: res = max(re.findall(r'(a{2,})', s))

In [129]: res
Out[129]: 'aaaaaaa'

In [130]: len(res)
Out[130]: 7
```

с использованием [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
In [138]: from itertools import groupby

In [139]: max(len(list(g)) for c,g in groupby(s) if c=='a')
Out[139]: 7
```